# Append does more than wanted

Tags: swift

I have a tabbar view controller with three tabs. I have implemented a global array in this tabBar controller in order to make it accessible from all the tabs. It is an array of type [[[Any]]]. I wanted to modify this array from the first tab by appending an element but the problem is that instead of just appending the element, it modifies the existing element too. Can you help me pls ? Thanks.

Here is the definition of the array :

```
var invoices: [[[Any]]] = []
```

Here is the appending :

```
let tabBar = tabBarController as! baseTabBarController
tabBar.invoices.append(cells)
```

P.S: The append is done in a view controller connected to the first view controller (child of tabbar view controller) by a segue link.

Comment: "but the problem is that instead of just appending the element, it modifies the existing element too" what do you mean by this? What is `cells`?

Answer (score 1):

You really need to give more information to get more personalised answers.

However, your Array is a **three - dimensional - array**, which means that you have an array inside an array inside an array.

When performing the `append` Method on an array, it always adds a new element to the end of this array.

**In your case:** The element that is added is of type `[[Any]]`, which is a **two - dimensional - array**.

**NOTE:** More - dimensional - arrays are a bit tricky. What your code does is appending a new `two - dimensional - array` at the end of your outer array, **not adding a new Any to your inner array!**

However, the `append` Method will never modify existing Elements, so please check your syntax again, since more - dimensional - arrays are tricky.

Comment: I don't want to add a new Any to the inner array. I want it to add a multidimensional array as you said. If you want I can share my code but it is a bit unreadable as it is my first project. I will add comments if you want.

Comment: @todoMan I understood that you want to add a new two - dimensional - array to the end, however, the append - Method does neither change any of the existing elements nor the order of the elements inside the array. This means, that the issue is somewhere else, maybe you have two similar named arrays or you changed the value somewhere else and forgot. You need to check your code again for any array - manipulations. Feel free to post your code, maybe I can find something.

Comment: Ok, here is the folder : https://github.com/m4thus4n/project. Just you have to create a folder with name "invoice" and place all the files other than the project file (there was a problem with GitHub). I have added a mark to where I append.

Comment: Have you found anything ?